# JDBC will let me SELECT, but errors out when I update?

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, cloudbees

So trying to read and then update a SQL database. I can read the information that comes from the DB but when I try to update it, there's always an error for some reason. I tried to get my syntax to work correctly using the MySQL application and it worked on there, but on here it doesn't want to..

Here's the code of note:

```
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM devices");

        Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
        String updateQuery = "UPDATE cb_internetot.devices" +
                "SET State = 6 " +
                "WHERE idDevices = 0;";
        stmt2.execute(updateQuery);
```

And here is the stacktrace I get:

```
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2820)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2769)
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:907)
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:791)
ConnAndReceive.connectAndQuery(ConnAndReceive.java:37)
ConnAndReceive.main(ConnAndReceive.java:15)
```

I'm running the DB on cloudbees so is it perhaps a security issue? I feel like it wouldn't be since I was able to SELECT from it correctly...

Comment: Your stacktrace is incomplete, you left out the exception class and error message

Answer (score 2):

Add a blank space between the table name and the `set` key word, otherwise the syntax of the sql statement is wrong:

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE cb_internetot.devices " +
                                                  ^
```